Third law of motion
Newton's third law states that for every action, there's an equal and opposite reaction. If that's the case, then how can anything move? if I push a box, then the reaction force would just cancel the force I used to push the box, wouldn't it?

The forces are acting on different bodies.

This is a paraphrasing, it is not what the law actually says.
